# Mockito - @SpyBean on bean with @RabbitListener annotation method creates another consumer

Tags: spring, mockito

I have an integration test class with @SpyBean annotation above one dependency and testing number of invocations using verify, however @SpyBean adds another queue consumer and verify method answering that there was no interactions with mock.

I've already tried some variations of Mocks, Spies, MockBeans. When I @Spy problematic bean, I have one consumer but no interactions with mock. @SpyBean creates another queue consumer but in one environment tests are passing (I've got right no of invocations so probably queue is consumed by mock) and on other environment queue is consumed by real(?) class, so method is not invoked. In both situations, I can see that problematic method is called by log output inside listener method. I have no ideas left how to solve it...

```
@Service 
public class MyDependency {

  @RabbitListener(queues = "someQueue")
  public void handleError(Message<?> message) {
      log.info(">>>>>> I'M HERE <<<<<<<<");
      handleFail(message);
  }
}
```

In test class I have

```
public class IntegrationTest {

  @SpyBean
  MyDependency myDependency;

  @Test
  void shouldPass() {   
    //some code... 
    verify(myDependency, times(2)).handleError(any());
  }
}
```

Expected result is: I've got two invocations of handleError method and no additional consumers are created
Actual: Additional consumer for queue is created (got two) and there's no iteractions with mock, method is not invoked (mockio says that) but I can see ">>> I'm here <<<" in logs